# Doom Emacs (DOOM v3.0.0-pre) - even after 'doom sync', i get "failed load doom' error when i open config.el

Tags: doom

I just installed Doom Emacs.  The version on the screen is DOOM v3.0.0-pre.  I wanted to setup the relative line number setup.  I put (setq doom-line-numbers-style 'relative) in config.el, exit out, and ran 'doom sync'.  Every time i open the config.el or init.el for that matter, i get "failed to load doom.  Profile init hasn't been generated.  Did you forget to run 'doom sync'" message on top of the screen.  Am I using the wrong version of Doom?
How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some variables configuration, you don't need to sync; this is needed when to add/modify packages, usually there must be a corresponding modification in file `packages.el` in your `doom.d` folder.

Searching for variable `doom-line-numbers-style` reveals nothing, there is a local variable `doom--line-number-style` however, but this should not be used.

Quoting from `docs/faq.org` file:

> To change the style of line numbers, change the value of the
> ~display-line-numbers-type~ variable. It accepts the following values:

- t            normal line numbers
- 'relative    relative line numbers
- 'visual      relative line numbers in screen space
- nil          no line numbers

and in your `config.el` file:

```
(setq display-line-numbers-type 'relative)
```

If you need to live revert to other style, there is the
function `doom/toggle-line-numbers` (call it with `M-x`).

Comment: I think one of the issue was that i was running the emacs version 27 with doom emacs.  i've uninstalled the emacs using the apt and downloaded the source for version 28 and built it.   Still getting the error message to run 'doom sync' but the display-line-numbers-type 'relative is working now along with other changes i've made.  Thank you.

Comment: You must run the command ```doom doctor``` to see what is wrong - maybe post all messages from that command and someone else will be able to suggest some corrections.